# How to get correct lat long of selected place from google auto complete

Tags: swift

i am using Google Places Auto complete SDK, when a places is selected, its name printed out correctly but if i try get lat long, it returns only -180 for both.

here is my Code

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace)
    {
        print("Place name: \(String(describing: place.name))")
        print("Place ID: \(String(describing: place.placeID))")
        print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")

        print("Selected Lat \(place.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("Selected Lng \(place.coordinate.longitude)")

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
enter code here
```

and here is output
[image]

Comment: a lot of other places..

Comment: 31.503906, 74.331996

Comment: these are correct lat long for... Kalma Chowk Flyover